# url rewriting with apache2 / php (symfony2)

Tags: php, apache, symfony

Consider the following URL:

```
http://dns/ePhotograph/web/app.php/home
```

I would like to use URL rewriting so that it is accessible from the following URL:

```
http://dns/home
```

How can I do that with apache  ?

**EDIT**

This is my vhost file:

```
    <VirtualHost 88.191.157.10:80>
 ServerName myurl.fr
ServerAlias www.myurl.fr
ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/ePhotograph/web
DirectoryIndex app.php
<Directory "/var/www/ePhotograph/web">
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from All
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your virtualhost configuration, you need to point your document root to `web/` and set your index to `app.php`. Then use a rewrite rule to push all urls to `app.php`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  DocumentRoot "c:\wamp\www\symfony\web"
  DirectoryIndex app.php
  <Directory "c:\wamp\www\symfony\web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I guess this code should be added to the httpd-vhosts.conf file ? It's nowhere to be found on my server. I just don't get it. And the httpd.conf file is empty. What am I missing ?

Comment: ok, i'm almost there. It took me a while to figure out that in Ubuntu I had to add a vhost file to sites-enabled folder. Anyway, I get a 404 when I browse to http://dns/home. If I browse to http://dns/app.php/home it works fine, meaning that at least my vhost file is taken into account. But the rewrite rule is not working. I think this is because Symfony router is taking over. How can I solve that ?

Comment: @Sam Check to make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled and restart apache.

Comment: yes it is enabled. I've already checked that. In fact, when I browse to http://dns, I'm redirected to http://dns/app.php so it is working. But that's not what I want.I want to browse to http://dns/home and be redirected to http://dns/app.php/home, which does not happen

Comment: I thought I had it working but I was wrong. I've edited my post so you can see the content of my vhost file. If you browse to the URL http://www.samuel-berthelot.fr/app.php/accueil then it works, but as soon as you remove the app.php part, it fails. Yet I've done the rewrite as per your recommendation. Any idea what I'm missing ?

Comment: I'll mark your post as answer because you've helped me get rid of the web part of the url. The app.php part still don't work though